# ASP.Net - Reducing repetitive code for validation - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form with many drop down list boxes on. Each of which I am showing or hiding a row of a table based on its value then adding a requiredfieldvalidator to the text box contained in that row. I am doing this on the selectedindexchanged event of each drop down list, the code for which can be seen below:

```
Protected Sub cbOffCover_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbOffCover.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cbOffCover.SelectedValue = "N" Then
        OffCoverRow.Visible = True
        Dim rfOffcover As RequiredFieldValidator = New RequiredFieldValidator
        With rfOffcover
            .ControlToValidate = txtOffCover.ID
            .SetFocusOnError = True
            .ErrorMessage = "*"
            .ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End With
        OffCoverCell.Controls.Add(rfOffcover)
    Else
        OffCoverRow.Visible = False
        Dim c As Control
        For Each c In OffCoverCell.Controls
            If c.ID = "rfOffCover" Then
                OffCoverCell.Controls.Remove(c)
            End If
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

I then reuse this code for each drop down list to show/hide a differently named row and apply validation to a different text box.

My question being is there a better way of doing this? I don't know exactly how but I can't help but think I don't have to write this much code (or copy/paste) over and over again for each drop down list. Is it possible to write a function/class that will do the work and I can just call that instead? Might seem basic but i'm new to asp/vb. Many thanks

Comment: You could simply handle more than one Event with the same method.
Yimply copy the part after Handles and add it on one big event handler.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the reply. I don't think this will work as the name of the row to show/hide and the textbox to validate changes with each drop down list. I don't think I made this clear in my original question so I have edited it to provide more information

Comment: Well, you could refactor your solution, so that cbOffCover is dynamically selected, depending on the passed in Dropdown. Something like Dim Row = getRow(sender)
where getRow contains the logic to identify the correct row.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in a function that returns a boolean.  When you call the function, pass it the combobox itself and whatever values you want to validate against.  If it matches, return true.  Try something like this:

```
Public Function ValidateComboBox(someComboBox as ComboBox, expectedValue as String)
  Dim result as Boolean = False
  If someComboBox.SelectedValue = expectedValue Then
        result = True
        OffCoverRow.Visible = True
        Dim rfOffcover As RequiredFieldValidator = New RequiredFieldValidator
        With rfOffcover
            .ControlToValidate = txtOffCover.ID
            .SetFocusOnError = True
            .ErrorMessage = "*"
            .ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End With
        OffCoverCell.Controls.Add(rfOffcover)
  Else
        OffCoverRow.Visible = False
        Dim c As Control
        For Each c In OffCoverCell.Controls
            If c.ID = "rfOffCover" Then
                OffCoverCell.Controls.Remove(c)
            End If
        Next c
  End If

  Return result

End Function
```

Of course, modify it to fit your needs.  Maybe you only return the value, and do the other stuff inside the control's SelectedIndexChanged method.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I will try and adapt this to my needs. I've got it all working with repetitive coding but will revisit it to try this out